# Show Spinner at the center of UI

Tags: office-ui-fabric

How will show a spinner at the center of the page and all the contents in the page gets blurred while showing the spinner?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use CSS, here is an example: https://codepen.io/mohamedhmansour/pen/qJggma

Basically make sure your html and body are maximized:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}
```

And the div that wraps the spinner should center the contents. Use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox):

```
#loader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: white;
}
```

And finally your component is just the following:

```
let { Spinner, SpinnerSize } = window.Fabric;

ReactDOM.render((
  <Spinner size={SpinnerSize.large} />
), document.getElementById('loader'));
```

Same thing applies with CSS-in-JS.